# 12 V, 7 Ah equivalent transformer

Tags: 12v, electromagnet

I am trying to power a maglock.  The specs say its current draw is 12 V, 500 mA.

It works fine when powered by a 12V battery (Mighty Max ML7-12).

However, it doesn't work when powered by a 12 VDC, 2A DC transformer.

I am just wondering where I'm going wrong here and what I can use to power this thing.

Comment: "Ah" is a rating of battery capacity (i.e. can output 7 amps for 1 hour).  It's a nonsense rating for a transformer.

Comment: Understood.  Just added that to clarify the specs of the battery I am using.

Comment: Do you have the polarity right?  (i.e. you didn't mix + and - )

Comment: Measure the output voltage of your 'transformer' ---Unloaded (not connected) and loaded (with the maglock).   Report back with your findings....

Comment: Kyle, thank you, will do.  Unloaded, it's 12.03V.  This is connected to my gate outside and it's raining now.  I will take a loaded measurement ASAP and get back with you.

Comment: Kyle, using the 12V battery, the loaded voltage is the same as the unloaded.  ~13V.

Using the 12VDC transformer, it's strange.  It goes from ~1V, to nothing, then to ~1V.  Back and forth like that.  ???

Comment: That symptom almost certainly means the adaptor is shutting down due to it's sensing an overcurrent condition.   It cycles on & off waiting for the "short circuit" to be relieved.  I think the MagLock must have a very significant "inrush current" .  This is normal... You've seen your kitchen lights dim when the fridge kicks on I'm sure... Same effect... When starting up, stuff often requires much higher than normal current.   Your solution is a more powerful  (higher amperage)  power supply.   Your battery can supply WAY more current that your adaptor, that's why it works.

Comment: Kyle, thank you so much. I will try another adapter, something like 5A.

Answer (score 0):

The output of a transformer is AC, not DC. You need a 12VDC, 1A or more power supply.

Comment: Maybe OP edited his question after this answer, but currently it says "12V 2A DC transformer".    If that's the case, my suspicion is that the power-on surge current is greater than 2A, or the "DC" is just rectified AC (i.e. no capacitor)

Comment: Hi, thank you.  I have the Rollerhouse 12V DC 2-Amp Plug-in Transformer

Comment: Amazon knows nothing about electronics and should call it a "regulated switching power supply", not a transformer.